# Why am I getting a console error on addClass, but everything still works as expected?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is a jQuery snippet intended to change the active class on a navigation item based on the scroll position. Everything works fine when tested, but I continue getting the error below.

**Error:**

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'addClass')`

```
document.addEventListener("scroll", onScroll);

function onScroll(event) {
  let scrollPosition = $(document).scrollTop();
  let current;
  $("aside a").removeClass("clicked");
  $("aside a").each(function () {    
    let currentLink = $(this);
    let refElement = $(currentLink.attr("href"));
    if ( refElement.position().top+380 <= scrollPosition ) { 
      current = $(this);
    }
  });
  current.addClass("clicked");
}
```

Comment: Seems you never go through the `if` thus `current` is undefined. You might want to put `current.addClass("clicked");` inside the if condition

Comment: Change your `let` to `let current = $(".clicked");` then it will always have a jquery collection to apply .addClass to, even if that collection is empty / nonsense.   Or `let current = null; ...  if (current != null) current.AddClass...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if ( refElement.position().top+380 <= scrollPosition ) {
```

When the condition is false, current is undefined hence the error. If it still works as expected then you probably want to move the   `current.addClass("clicked");` inside the if statement.

Comment: Inside the condition didn't work either.

Comment: I guess you could try to do if (current) before the .addClass in either version of the code, that should clear the error. If you can make a stackblitz that reproduces the issue I could have a look. Without that you would need to find the reason why the ${this} would return undefined for the case where the .addClass is within the if (refElement... statement